# I'm trying to print this without just doing println for each line

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, printing

I want to print this by using nest for lops and/or if statements

```
ABABABAB
BABABABA
ABABABAB
BABABABA
ABABABAB
BABABABA
ABABABAB
BABABABA
```

```
public class chess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < 1; r++)
                {
                    if (r%2== 0)
                    {
                            System.out.print("A");

                    }

                    if (r%2==1)
                    {
                            System.out.print("B");

                    }
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
                {
                    if (x%2== 0)
                    {
                            System.out.print("B");

                    }

                    if (x%2 == 1)
                    {
                            System.out.print("A");

                    }
                }

            }

    }

}
```

output is just: `ABABABAB`

I don't want to just do `System.out.println("BABABABA")` back & forth.

THANKS! I'm new to coding and any help is appreciated.

Comment: `I don't want to just do System.out.println("BABABABA")`.. what do you want to use ?

Comment: nested for loops, and/or if statements

Comment: Change `x < 1` and `r < 1` to `x < 8` and `r < 8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code, you should obtain what you want without using `System.out.println()` once.

You just check if the sum of `i` and `j` is a pair and print `A` if it is, `B` if it is not.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++){
        if ((i+j)%2 == 0) System.out.print("A");
        else System.out.print("B");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid if's whenever possible:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++){
        System.out.print( (char)('A' + (i+j)%2) );
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

(You can replace %2 with %3, %4,... for other interesting patterns.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
        {
            if (r % 2 == 0)
            {
                 System.out.print("A");
            }
            if (r % 2 == 1)
            {
                 System.out.print("B");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
        {
            if (r % 2 == 0)
            {
                 System.out.print("B");
            }
            if (r % 2 == 1)
            {
                 System.out.print("A");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Changing the value `i` iterates up to will change the number of rows, and changing the value `r` iterates up to will change the number of `A`'s and `B`'s you print out per row.

Comment: Haha oh dear, whoops. Should be fixed!